# How to search blob files in a date range

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-explorer

I’m using Azure storage explorer to find specific files. The files loaded are very old and short by date looks not showing the correct results.

Is there any way in which I can give date range and it will show me the files in between those date range?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way in which I can give date range and it will show me
> the files in between those date range?

Unfortunately no. Azure Blob Storage has very limited server-side filtering capabilities and filtering by date is not one of them. What you have to do is list all blobs in the container and then apply filtering on the client side.

An alternative would be to import this information in an Azure Cognitive Search Index and there you will be able to perform all kinds of filtering. I wrote a blog post about it long time ago that you may find useful: https://gauravmantri.com/2014/08/25/making-azure-blob-storage-searchable-using-azure-search-service/.

Comment: Those blobs ( block blobs) are automatically /programmatically generated in the container and I wanted to see those via storage explorer. The problem is why can’t I see when I do short by dates? Or is there any ways I can write a small program which will extract the blobs and put it in excel with its date created?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Storage Explorer only displays 100 blobs at a time and the sorting only works on the data fetched on the client side. You will have to go through all the pages and sort them to see the relevant data.